# The real difference between the MessageDigest`s two update methods?

Tags: java, md5

Example one:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  digest.update(buffer, 0, len);
}
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest());
return  bigInt.toString(16);
```

Example two:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  digest.update(buffer);
}
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest());
return  bigInt.toString(16);
```

In the above two examples, I use two different update methods. When I pass a same file path, the two operations return two different results. Is the update method append mode? Why I got different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one works, the second doesn't. The `read` does not necessarily fill the full buffer, but in the second example you always send all bytes to the digest.

Comment: Oh my God, I just lose the point you have pointed out! It saves my life. Thanks very much.